How to compute the energy of a non-eigenstate in a Heisenberg limited form?
Let us have a Hamiltonian $H$ and a state $|\psi\rangle = \sum_i a_i |E_i\rangle$, a linear combination of eigenstates $|E_i\rangle$ of $H$ with eigenvalues $E_i$. What is the best way to achieve a Heisenberg-limited measurement of the energy of $\psi$, $E_\psi = \sum_i a_i E_i$.
If $\psi$ were an eigenstate, Quantum Phase Estimation provides an answer. However, if it were not we would have to sample the result of QPE subsequently. I have also considered an old Grover paper to compute the mean of a probability distribution, with an additional $O(1/\epsilon)$ overhead over QPE (already $O(1/\epsilon)$). Is there a way to do it better?

Dumb question but what's wrong with sampling?

Not dumb, it's just that the scaling would be $O(1/\epsilon^2)$, right? And we'd prefer to achieve $O(1/\epsilon)$.

Thanks! My poor-man's "computer-science" mind is wondering what you mean by the Heisenberg limit? There's a time-energy uncertainty in the precision you'd get from the Quantum Phase Estimation even if $|\psi\rangle$ where promised to be an eigenstate of $H$, because you'd need to actually simulate $\exp(-iHt)$ many times to avoid conflict with the No-Fast-Forwarding Theorem. But I don't think that's what you mean by the Heisenberg limit, is it?

I think it is! In Quantum Phase Estimation you need to call the unitary $U = e^{-iH\tau}$ $O(1/\epsilon)$ times to achieve precision $\epsilon$ in the measurement. The thing is, when you do QPE, you will measure the energy of one eigenstate in the superposition, so you'd need to sample $O(1/\epsilon^2)$ many points to get an expectation value of the average of the distribution. So overall the cost would be $O(1/\epsilon^3)$. The question is improving this to inverse linear.

It seems that if you want to get a better accuracy than $1/\epsilon^3$ you will need protocols which use several copies of $|\psi\rangle$ at once, since otherwise there is nothing which distinguishes $|\psi\rangle$ from a mixture of eigenstates, so repeated phase estimation and averaging should be optimal in that case. --- Does the Grover method give you $1/\epsilon^2$?

BTW, is your question really "What is the best way to achieve a Heisenberg-limited measurement", or rather "Is it possible to achieve ... "?

One naive attempt could be to take $|\psi\rangle^{\otimes N}$ and do phase estimation for $\mathcal H = N^{-1}\sum H_i$ ($H_i$ is $H$ acting on the $i$th copy.) For each eigenstate of $\mathcal H$, this will give Heisenberg-limited accuracy, and my feeling is that a central limit type argument should tell that the error from averaging the different eigenstates concentrates rapidly.

I think some of the methods discussed in https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.129.240501 would work.

Here is a suggestion how to obtain a Heisenberg-limited energy estimation -- there's several details to be filled in, though.
You can run phase estimation on $N$ copies of the state, $|\Psi\rangle :=|\psi\rangle^{\otimes N}$, for
$$
\mathcal H = \tfrac1N\sum H_i\ ,
$$
where $H_i$ is the Hamiltonian $H$ acting on the $i$'th copy. Note that the energy expectation value of $\mathcal H$ in $|\Psi\rangle$ is the same as that of $H$ in $|\psi\rangle$.
For each energy eigenstate of $\mathcal H$, you will get Heisenberg-limited accuracy for the energy. On the other hand, as the number of copies increases, the probability to be in an eigenstate with an energy $\delta$-close to the average energy (that is, in a $\delta$-typical subspace) will converge exponentially due to the central limit theorem -- which is essence means that with correspondingly high probability, the phase estimation will return a value $\delta$-close to the desired average. Choosing $\delta$ sufficiently smaller than the desired accuracy $\epsilon$ (e.g. $\epsilon/2$, and run phase estimation with accuracy $\epsilon/2$) and then $N$ sufficiently large should give the desired result.

Thanks Norbert! What I am worried about this is that the central limit theorem converges with $\delta = O(N^{-1/2})$, so in practice this adds up another multiplicative cost actor of $\delta^2$. Would this not be the case?
But perhaps you mean using something like the median lemma in https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1549 which does indeed converge exponentially fast for the number of copies $N$. However, this requires the probability of each individual estimate to be away from the center to be small; which I think we do not have here.

@Pablo My point about the central limit theorem is a different one (so I think): My point is that if you draw a random eigenstate of $|\psi\rangle^{\otimes N}$, then the probability that its energy is $\delta$-close to the average should converge quite rapidly in N -- at least so I seem to remember. But I would have to check the precise statement; often in applications of typicality one just uses the fact that it converges (Chebychev), without looking at the convergence behavior. And it might well be that the minimum N needed to get a sufficiently large probability scales as $1/\delta^2$.

@Pablo Note that a priori a large $N$ is not problematic, since the computational time does not scale with $N$, at least not in a naive way. (The error in $\langle \mathcal H\rangle$ is the same as the error in $\langle H\rangle$, so it is independent of $N$.) Of course, for large $N$, this in essence means that we want relative low accuracy for the evolution under each $H_i$, which might be a differently scaling (and possibly not-so-well-analyzed) regime.

@NorbertSchuch what advantage do you get in running QPE on $\mathcal H$? Surely each $H_i$ commute?

Oh. Perhaps I am beginning to understand. Even though $[H_i,H_k]=0$, the top register of the QPE circuit doesn’t know that. You can double the number of times you simulate $\mathcal H$ in the QPE circuit, and halve the error in your overall estimation of $|\psi\rangle$’s energy…

@Mark Indeed; and note that the control register is the same for all $H_i$ and accumulates the phase: Thus, the estimate (hopefully) behaves more favorably than independent phase estimation carried out on each copy (which, as I argued in my comment below the question, should not allow to give the desired scaling, as it is would behave the same way as a mixture of eigenstates).

Thanks @NorbertSchuch. I think you are saying that by having $|\Psi\rangle$ be the product of a bunch of copies of $|\psi\rangle$ and $\mathcal H$ be the sum of a number of individual $H$, you increase the likelihood that (big) $|\Psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of (script) $\mathcal H$, even though (little) $|\psi\rangle$ need not be an eigenstate of (unscripted) $H$. Accordingly you can do normal phase estimation on $\mathcal H$ acting on $|\Psi\rangle$ to a greater precision, and you can be confident will give a good estimate of the energy of $|\psi\rangle$ with respect to $H$...

@Mark It is more than that (and that more is needed): The probability (if you were to measure in the energy eigenbasis) to be in an eigenstate with any specific energy will go down, but the probability to be in an eigenstate in a narrow energy band around the average will get as close to 1 as you want. So if you were to do perfect phase estimation, you would get a random eigenstate, but with $p\approx 1$, its energy would be $\delta$ away from the average -- which is all you want.

I may be wrong about this but when you run the QPE on some state $|\psi\rangle$ by simulating some Hamiltonian $H$, your precision is limited at least by:

The error in the simulation of $U=\exp(-iHt)$;
The precision you decide to choose for the phase estimation with the (inverse) Fourier transform; and
The number of times you have to sample from the QPE using multiple copies of $|\psi\rangle$.

You can increase the precision with the first factor by using a larger Trotter factor or using more sophisticated Hamiltonian simulation.  You can increase the precision of the second by adding an additional qubit of precision but you're still limited by the No Fast-Forwarding Theorem and you'd need to run your circuit for twice as long for each qubit of precision:

As for the third factor, if we are promised that $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate then we only need to run the circuit once, because we'll get the phase right away.  If $|\psi\rangle$ is in a superposition of two or more eigenstates and we don't know how much each contributes to $|\psi\rangle$, then I think you're right that statistics tells us the number of times we need to call the QPE grows quadratically.
But I think it's somewhat similar to a classical test. If we are given an audio signal that we are promised is a pure tone, and we have magical Born-rule box that will let us sample from the signal to return its frequency, it only takes one sample for us to know what the tone is.  If we are given a signal that's a sum of two or more tones and we don't know the weight of each pure tone with respect to our signal, then I'm still pretty sure we'd have to run our Born box for a quadratic number of times to get a good estimte of $E_\psi$.

What I am looking for is a way to eliminate the third factor somehow.
